# What issues will I face when doing photoshop and design work on a curved monitor?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, hardware-recommendation, hardware, monitor

I've got this great deal online for a samsung curved monitor and printer combo so I've been thinking of buying the monitor for graphic design work. Due to the curved nature of the screen, I fear that it may make the images,vectors or my photoshop canvas warped,stretched. I'm wondering if it is okay or not to use the monitor for my projects, I'm in need of your advice.

Comment: No big eal with the curved nature of them.

Comment: They're designed for gaming but there's no real reason why you can't use it for design work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes minimal difference in terms of distortion. Unless you do a lot of perspective correction for architectural shots and the like I wouldn't worry about that at all.

If you work on critical work though you might want to make sure it is an IPS Panel with AdobeRGB, I don't believe Samsung makes any that are. If you don't work on highly color critical work that might not make a difference to you though.